# Can't sync build using itunes or wirelessly using testflight or diawi

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning

I just finished creating an iphone app.When i debug it in my device using Xcode,it works.
When i archive it using my Ad-hoc distribution profile or the debug profile and then try syncing it with itunes , it shows up in my device (iPhone 5S) and shows installing but then gives an error message **" Unable to Download Apps "App Name " and 1 other application could not be installed at this time**

At one point in development process , **I did change my product name from Xcode(ver 5.0) by tapping on the project name and following the rename process. I changed it from a simple Word to Something like "Who's Birthday Is It?".
Could this have caused the problem??**

Also after a couple of times trying to install from the copied thing ,the error message changes to something like  **"Unable to Download Apps "App Name " and 4 other items could not be installed at this time"**

**Then I checked the provisioning profiles added to my device and i see some old profiles added to device ,the profiles i've already deleted from member center.
What could be causing this??**

I have already gone through most of the answers on stackoverflow.I have already checked for the following things :

My Bundle Identifier matches to that of the provisioning i've used.
My Device's UDID is added to the provisioning profile i've used for preparing the .ipa

Please help me out.I've been at this for days now.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting the .ipa and .plist on a server and downloading it from a webpage onto your iPhone? You can use itms-services protocol.

Comment: @PaulVon How does that help??How do i do that??

Comment: Also I worked around my problem by --                                **Making a whole new app id ** then  **renaming my app name , bundle identifier and everything.. **... **Deleted all my current provisioning profiles...created new ones and then used them ...** It Worked. But Since i had already created an app account with that bundle identifier on itunes connect , i'll have think of another name for my app :(